# Having Problems when trying to print a value from a dictionary using a random key in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to print the values from the dictionary into a random order as part of a game I am making.
the problem is that for some reason I am not able to print the value from the key

```
var die:UInt32 = 0
let windCard = [1:"1 Left",  2:"2 Left",  3:"1 Down Left",  4:"2 Down Left",  5:"1 Down",  6:"2 Down",  7:"1 Right Down",  8:"2 Right Down", 9:"1 Right", 10:"2 Right" ]
die = arc4random()%10+1
print("The wind blow the mosquitoes \(windCard[die:Int])")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
print("The wind blow the mosquitoes \(windCard[die:Int])")
```

to

```
print("The wind blow the mosquitoes \(windCard[Int(die)]!)")
```

Comment: thanks for your help, what would you suggest my approach was?

Comment: I'd use an array, not a dictionary keyed by number.